# How to adaptively select stimuli in paired comparison experiment?

Tags: paired-data, active-learning

I have 500 items of which I want to know how much they are liked by a specific expert.

To find how much they are liked, I wish to use paired comparisons since this yields more accurate results than asking for a single rating for each item.

Now, if I where to present all combinations of these 500 items to the expert, this would be too many comparisons to handle. Therefore, I am looking for a way to only compare those items that would bring the most information about their likeability.

I know that, for other models, adaptive design optimization can be used. The idea is that after each trial that pair of items is selected for the following trial that would bring the most information about the model parameters. I have done that with the ADOPy package for models that have a limited number of parameters. However, as far as I understand, in my case I would have 500 parameters -> one likeability parameter for each of the 500 items.

What I have tried:

- I was able to implement this algorithm:  10.1007/s11042-017-4977-2. However, it requires that there is an already existing rank order that is then improved. I am looking for an algorithm to select the stimuli that starts without any prior knowledge about the rank or likeability of the items.
- I have looked at other algorithms that have been proposed for my task but they all seem to require that either there are some feature variables accompanying each item or that some absolute values for the latent parameter are known a priori. However, in my case, I will start with only the unordered list of 500 items and want to get most information in as few comparisons as possible.

My questions are:

1. Which model would be appropriate for my data? Bradley-Terry seems to require that each pair has been observed more than once. However, this seems not realistic for my case.
2. (How) can adaptive design optimization be done for such a model?

It seems like a simple problem to me that many people should have had, but I had no success so far.

Comment: This is unclear. If you already have the 500 comparisons, why do you need active learning? It does not make much sense for me to estimate 500 latent variables, each for one pair?

Comment: I have 500 items, not 500 comparisons. I need latent variables for each of the items and I want to do so by comparing each of them against each other (or better worded: I am looking for a way to get the latent variables without having to compare each of them against each other)

Comment: Can you please try to update your post (by editing it) to clarify the situation. Four days without much response indicates that I am not the only one having problems understanding this.

Comment: Will do, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the method used, I believe this goal is fundamentally unachievable and impractical. What are these 500 items? Goods/services? Manufacturing components? Food ingredients? If yes, it seems reasonable to prioritize them by profitability and offer for comparison in this order. Not offering for pairwise comparisons whose items that have been inferior in any comparison in the past. The latter, of course, if the goal is to find a set of the most preferred item.

Comment: What you propose is what is described in the algorithm that I linked and have already implemented. However, I am rather confident that there is a possiblity to do this without any prior info in a dynamic fashion. I am thinking of a similar approach to what is described here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-020-01386-4

Comment: As I see your task, it is just sorting. Sorting with the minimum (expected/best case/worst case, whatever benchmark you choose) number of comparisons for 500 items. This is probably the question for developers, not stats.

Comment: It would be, if I accept that all items are to be tested against each other. However, this is what I try to avoid. See these examples: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330511386_Accelerated_Experimental_Design_for_Pairwise_Comparisons 10.1007/s10994-012-5297-4

Comment: Nope. Sorting algorithms don't assume one needs to compare all with all. It would be a huge waste of a computer's resources.

Comment: Fair point. My point was: I do not need a complete rank list in the end but rather I am looking for a method that would give the pair that would give the most information about the rank order. Please see the links I attached.

Comment: Yeah, I looked, I just thought those papers are about a different thing. Could you please explain how one pair can give more information about the (overall) rank order of 500 items than any other pair. I just don't understand what is meant by that... Or maybe your set of 500 items has an unusual ordering like some weird type of [partial ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set)...

Comment: Let's say we know from previous trials that itemA > itemB, that itemB > itemC, and that itemB > itemD. Comparing A to C would very probably not bring any new information. However, comparing C and D would give us new information, so it would be better to display C vs. D than A vs C.

Comment: Yeah, but this is exactly what the effective sorting algorithms are all about. Nothing more, nothing less. And you still cannot order a set unless you have compared each item with something at least once. If even one item out of those 500 has never been compared with anything, you cannot determine its place in that order. Or do I miss something?

Comment: I do not know enough about sorting algorithms to answer that, tbh. As far as I see, a sorting algorithm can see the value of each item and then does the comparing. This is not the case in experiments with paired comparison where the value of an item can only be learned through comparison.

Comment: What the sorting algorithms does is just ordering the list according to some parameter of the items (sometimes items in a list can have the same value, sometimes they can be vectors/tuples/arrays of different lengths/strings of characters, complex [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) objects, etc.). If a comparison of those two arbitrary objects can always return one of the three values (greater, less, equal), sorting can be carried out. Ideally in the most efficient way, minimizing the time, memory, etc. I see no difference between that and your goal...

Comment: There are different sorting algorithms optimized to minimize the number of comparisons (irrespective of how much those comparisons take of the computer's resources). Some of them are proved to be best for unordered lists/sets of specific lengths. You may want to find the one specifically good for the list of 500 items.

Comment: I will look into that, thank you!